# does iPhone connected to MacBook use power from usb or its own battery?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, usb, battery, storage

Does aniPhone connected to a MacBook by USB, use power from USB or its own battery?
I want to use the iPhone camera overhead for teaching art on Zoom. Answers to this kind of heavy tech question/research are necessary to avoid a $500-$1,000 iPhone purchase mistake.
Similarly, does iPhone streaming a Zoom class, use it's own storage space or that of the USB connected MacBook?

Answer (score 4):

The iPhone always draws its power from its own battery. However, when connected by USB to a MacBook Pro, it will at the same time charge the battery. So depending on your use-case, it is commonly possible to run the iPhone indefinitely in this mode. Remember to power the MacBook Pro from its charger, and ensure that the MacBook Pro is not so heavily taxed that it actually uses more power than the charger supplies.

When using Zoom on an iPhone, any storage used would be on the iPhone itself - not on an USB-connected MacBook Pro. However, streaming a Zoom class doesn't really use up any storage worthwhile mentioning - unless you're recording it.

Comment: "Indefinitely" --- only if the MBP is plugged into the mains, of course.

Comment: Yes, I thought that was obvious - but I'll add it to the answer!